# ASP NET Core MVC database list view with sort all columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, listview

I have a list view in my `FileManager.cshtml` page (code below) and I need to implement sort function to all columns that are displayed on this view. I looked through some examples on the web and YouTube but there are Javascript functions or "hand-made" namespaces. Is it possible to do it without `JScript`?
Thank you for help!

Function in my controller that displays list view from `dbo.Files` filtered by logged user ID:

```cs
private readonly TextCloudContext Context;

public IActionResult FileManager()
{
    var user = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    var items = Context.Files.Where(f => f.UserID == user).ToList();
    return View(items);
}
```

String in TextCloudContext.cs with get and set values in "Files" table from my SQL Server table "Files":

```
public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
```

`File.cs` model that initialize values for Db parameter in `TextCloudContext` and display column names in my `FileManagerView.cshtml`

```
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "File Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "File Type")]
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public TextCloudUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and finally View with table class:

```html
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Extension)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Actions")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Extension)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>               
            <td> - this razor Html doesn't work yet
                @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { fileName = item.ToString() }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: check this one out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/perform-paging-searching-sorting-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1),here is a working demo like below:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<File>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="FileManager" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</a>      
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="FileManager" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["ExtensionSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Extension)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="FileManager" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["DateSortParm"]">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Actions")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Extension)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { fileName = item.ToString() }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult FileManager(string sortOrder)
    {
        //var user = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
        //var items = Context.Files.Where(f => f.UserID == user);  //you may change this..

        //for easy testing,i just create data manually..
        var items = new List<File>()
        {
            new File(){ Id=1, Data="a", Date="2019-8-9", Extension=".jpg", Name="file1", UserID="1"},
            new File(){ Id=1, Data="b", Date="2019-7-9", Extension=".png", Name="file2", UserID="2"},
            new File(){ Id=1, Data="c", Date="2019-5-8", Extension=".png", Name="file3", UserID="3"},
            new File(){ Id=1, Data="d", Date="2019-4-7", Extension=".jpg", Name="file4", UserID="4"}
        }.AsQueryable();

        ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        ViewData["ExtensionSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Extension" ? "ext_desc" : "Extension";
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                break;
            case "Date":
                items = items.OrderBy(s => s.Date);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date);
                break;
            case "Extension":
                items = items.OrderBy(s=>s.Extension);
                break;
            case "ext_desc":
                items = items.OrderByDescending(s => s.Extension);
                break;
            default:
                items = items.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                break;
        }
        return View(items);
    }
```

Result:

[image]